# Kendo Js: Show previous dates which are disabled

Tags: javascript, date, kendo-ui

I am facing an issue using Kendo Js Date Time Picker.

**The situation is**: "I have a date time picker which can only allow dates from current time onwards. 
Those pages have already been saved, when I am trying to show the date, the dates aren't showing though it became a back date.

**My concern is**: The input should show the date which has already been saved(Whether that is past or present), but it shouldn't allow user to select back date.

The code are below.
`<input id="datetimepicker" />`

```
let options = { //Setting options for the datepicker
  value: new Date(),
  dateInput: true,
  disableDates: function (date) {
    if (date <= new Date()) { 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
};
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker(options);

const priorValue = new Date("8/31/2022 2:18 PM"); // Let Already selected date
let selector = "#datetimepicker";

let datetimepicker = $(selector).data("kendoDateTimePicker");
datetimepicker.value(priorValue);
datetimepicker.trigger("change");

function roundToNearest30(date) { //Function to round minutes to nearest 30 minute.
  date = new Date(date);
  const minutes = 30;
  const ms = 1000 * 60 * minutes;

  return new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / ms) * ms);
}
```

For your reference [a sample dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Satrughna/UKedaqUv)
I need to show the selected date which is disabled.

Comment: kendoDatePicker has a property for disabling dates (it can be an array or a function
check the example on the documentation https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/disable-dates

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But my concern is showing the dates which has disabled but previously saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disableDates configuration to disable prior dates and the [month.content](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/configuration/month#monthcontent) configuration to define how the dates will be rendered and show/hide dates conditionally:

```
<script id="cell-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span class="#= (data.date <= new Date() && !isInArray(data.date, data.dates)) ? 'hidden' : 'visible' #">#= data.value #</span>
</script>
```

Here is a [sample dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsagUjUZ).

Comment: I have updated the code, Please do check the link. My concern is to show selected date in the textbox. when even it is disabled. [link](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Satrughna/UKedaqUv)

Comment: Setting a disabled date as value of the DAtePicker/DateTimePicker is not supported. Maybe you can try visually disabling the dates with a custom template, and then using the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151446/kendo-ui-datepicker-getting-the-previous-value/16153238#16153238) to check whether the selected date is prior or not and preventing the selection.

Comment: Yes, That was the only option I was thinking. But it is a lengthier one. So I was searching if there any pre defined method. Thanks a lot. @Aleksandar.